# TextBox should occupy available space and not grow when filled with text

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I do have a Grid with two columns and two rows. In the first column, first row I do have this:

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label Content="Text:"/>
        <TextBox Name="TB_Text" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="120" />
        <Button Name="BT_TextApply" Content="Apply" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="BT_TextApply_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I have "rows" (Horizontal StackPanels within a Vertical StackPanel) consisting of a Label, a Textbox and a button that belongs together.

The StackPanels got the attribute `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` so that they use the complete space within their Grid cell, this is OK.

But now I want my three elements also to fill the complete available space of the StackPanel, but I don't get it to work.

**Current behaviour**

- The Label has no width it occupies the space that the text in `content` needs, this is at the moment fine.
- The Textbox has a minimum width and gets bigger when I fill it with text,
- the button is on the right of the Texbox and is moved to the right when the TextBox gets bigger and disappears when it is moved outside the StackPanel

**Wanted behaviour**

- The Label has no width it occupies the space that the text in `content` needs, this is at the moment fine.
- The Button should have a fixed width (no problem) and should stick to the right border of my StackPanel, this is not working
- The TextBox should use the rest of the space in between and not more, even when filled with more text than fits in.

Is there something like a "max" attribute for my TextBox dependend on the size of the StackPanel?

Comment: @Josh thanks that did it. I already tried dockpanel, but I didn't put the TextBox as last element. Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks stema.  I didn't have the time to try it so I wasn't sure if that would work or not.

Instead of a StackPanel, have you tried using a DockPanel with last child fill set to true? If you dock the label left and the button right. Then ensure the textbox is the last child element of the dockpanel, I would think the size of the textbox would fill the remaining space if its HorizontalAlignment is set to stretch.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is the solution I came up with using Josh's answer:

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <DockPanel  Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True">
        <Label Content="Text:" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <Button Name="BT_TextApply" Content="Apply" Width="75" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="BT_TextApply_Click" />
        <TextBox Name="TB_Text"/>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The important parts are: The `DockPanel` needs the attribute `LastChildFill="True"`, then list the items in the DockPanel that should "dock" somewhere and tell them to dock `DockPanel.Dock="Left"` and `DockPanel.Dock="Right"` and as last item, place that one that should occupy the remaining space. (The attribute `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` seems not to be needed for the last element, I can't see a difference if its there or not.)